# DataTable takes 4-5 seconds for rendering data when use ajax data source

Tags: php, ajax, datatable

**DataTable** takes 4-5 seconds as loading time for rendering data  when use **ajax data source with client side processing** for 100 records.I have also used **defer render** property but there is no benefit.Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @sumit Why it wont take time, its server side, ajax sourced??

Comment: Ajax dataSource